# How can I create different animations for a mesh on Blender?

Tags: animation, mesh, timeline

I have an avatar mesh and I want to separate different animations, each animation in a different timeline in order to create blending animation. I do not know how to begin this process on Blender. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Check out the NLA Editor https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/editors/nla.html

Comment: If I'm correctly interpreting what you mean by "blending", this seems like a job for Shape Keys. http://www.blender.org/manual/animation/techs/shape/shape_keys.html?highlight=shape%20keys

Comment: Actually blending animation means mixing different animations.

Comment: @batFINGER But before using NLA Editor to mix different animations, I have to create the animations first. But I don't know how to do it using Action Editor. Do you know how? I tried to create 2 animations, but I wasn't able to separate them in different timelines.

Comment: Quick run thru with just start up file and default cube selected. Hit i and insert a keyframe, the cube now has an action. In the Action Editor hit Stash .. it is now in the NLA.  Add a new action by either hitting the + NEW button in the Action editor, or by simply adding a keyframe with the cube selected.  Once your actions are in the NLA you can slide them around on the timeline, for example walk animation from 1 to 100, run from 90 to 250.   There are options on how to blend the animations, on the link above.